# Log report in liquibase db migration tool

Tags: liquibase

I have implemented liquibase db migration framework in my application. I am running the command line tool of this framework. It is working fine. Now I need a success or failure report from the logs generated from this tool.

The error may be framework related (e.g. specifying wrong parameters on command line or specifying wrong database etc.) as well as database related (e.g. syntax error in sql query, any constraint violation error). Does anyone have any idea of how to generate that report, how to get logs etc.

Comment: No completely clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running liquibase from the command line you can test the return for code sucess or failure:

```
liquibase update && echo "It worked"
```

Example

```
$ liquibase update && echo "It worked"
Liquibase Home: /opt/liquibase-2.0.3
INFO 26/12/11 17:36:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 26/12/11 17:36:liquibase: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 26/12/11 17:36:liquibase: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 26/12/11 17:36:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
It worked
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. It is working fine. But I need to implement this approach on an intgration tool where a number of application are running (currently of the number 300+). I need little more detailed reporting for that. Can you please be able to suggest some. Thanks in advance.